# contenteditable="true" ArrowRight The key is not working

Tags: javascript, html

press down ArrowLeft: cursor position C123 -> B123

press down ArrowLeft: cursor position B123 -> A123

press down ArrowRight: The cursor disappears. why?

[image]

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><a contenteditable="false">A123</a><a contenteditable="false">B123</a><a contenteditable="false">C123</a></div>
```

Comment: but `ArrowLeft ` Works correctly, why ArrowRight don't work

Answer (score 1):

### There are too many solutions

1. Format your HTML with an indent
2. add `&nbsp;` space to split the `contenteditable="false"` items

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <a contenteditable="false">A123</a>
  <a contenteditable="false">B123</a>
  <a contenteditable="false">C123</a>
</div>

<!-- or `&nbsp;` -->

<div contenteditable="true"><a contenteditable="false">A123</a>&nbsp;<a contenteditable="false">B123</a>&nbsp;<a contenteditable="false">C123</a></div>
```